# How to make a subtitle on top of a <p> or just a tag

Tags: html, css

Currently I have this:

[image]

but I want to have it like this:

[image]

As you can see is my subtitle in the center and not at the start of the text. I am now stuck. This is my HTML:

```css
.UPS {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.btw {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.kasa {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 19px;
}

.centered {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="kasa  centered mt-4 mb-1">Waarom OBSTUDIOS?</div>
<div class="centered">
  <p class="centered UPS mb-3">Waar kwaliteit en betaalbaarheid elkaar ontmoeten, daar vindt u OBStudios. Wij bieden eersteklas fotografie en videografie tegen zeer concurrerende prijzen. Bereikbaarheid is een topprioriteit voor ons, want uw tijd is kostbaar. We luisteren aandachtig
    naar uw wensen en zorgen ervoor dat uw visie tot leven komt in elk project. Klanttevredenheid staat bij ons hoog in het vaandel en dat merkt u aan alles: van het eerste contact tot aan de levering van het eindproduct. Kies voor OBStudios, waar uw
    behoeften altijd voorop staan.
  </p>
</div>
```

I know I centered it with the center class but I did that to make it appear good on the photo.

Comment: Why use a div instead of a sub-headline (h2-h6) for a subtitle? Why wrap the paragraph in another div?

Comment: 1: true I could have just use a h-x. But that changes how it looks a bit. 2: Because the <p> doesn't center with the  class = centered and I dont know why. That is why it is a div.

Comment: Please add more details to the question. What framework are you using? I can't reproduce the issue with the code you have provided nor with adding Bootstrap dependencies.

Comment: I am only using bootstrap css also it is a simple question just getting the subtilt at the start of the subtext.

Comment: The title is at the start with the code you provided

Comment: Look at the images I added it is at the center of the paragraph. But I want it like the other picture at the start of the paragraph so not the start of the screen.

Comment: Again, the code you provided has output as the wanted layout. Press the "*Run code snippet*" button within your question

Comment: I copied your code into codepen.io and added bootstrap. It looks perfectly fine with the "Waarom OBSTUDIOS" aligned to the left same as the example you want. Have you tried clearing your cache? It could be that some styles are cached so you're seeing a false representation of what it actually looks like.

Comment: Ah I see why forget to add this: .centered{
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}

Comment: With this it shouldnt work do you know how to fix. My bad

Answer (score 0):

You should try to minimize custom CSS when using frameworks and solve styling issues with your framework if possible!

Also, you should fix your markup to be semantically correct as already pointed out in the comments.

Instead of using Flexbox to center everything you could simply use the `ms-auto me-auto` classes on the container, which also can be shortend to `mx-auto`:

```css
.UPS {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.kasa {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 19px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<section class="UPS mx-auto">
  <h2 class="kasa">Waarom OBSTUDIOS?</h2>
  <p>Waar kwaliteit en betaalbaarheid elkaar ontmoeten, daar vindt u OBStudios. Wij bieden eersteklas fotografie en videografie tegen zeer concurrerende prijzen. Bereikbaarheid is een topprioriteit voor ons, want uw tijd is kostbaar. We luisteren aandachtig
    naar uw wensen en zorgen ervoor dat uw visie tot leven komt in elk project. Klanttevredenheid staat bij ons hoog in het vaandel en dat merkt u aan alles: van het eerste contact tot aan de levering van het eindproduct. Kies voor OBStudios, waar uw
    behoeften altijd voorop staan.
  </p>
</section>
```